# surface view is destroyed with activity in android 4.0

Tags: android, service, android-camera, surfaceview, video-recording

I am working on an app which records video in background and  my program works perfectly in android 2.3 but when i run the same code in android 4.0 it crashes ,my log gives `surface view null` and shows `Surface View destroyed`.
My question is how can i run an activity on background without destroying the surface view since i am doing the recording code in service .

My code is similar to this [sites](http://pickerwengs.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-background-video-recorder-on.html) code

If any one has come across problem like this pls help me
Thank in Advance.